# How to Join three tables with one reference in the query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jpql

Hi is there a way to join three tables like this but I can't change the reference of the column `code.id` at the query because I am creating a dynamic query for a search filter for this reference

Here is the code looks like

there are 4 tables bill, expense_distribution, item_distribution, project_code

*columns in the bill - id, name, ...etc
columns in the expense_distribution - id, bill_id, project_code_id, ...etc
columns in the item_distribution - id, bill_id, project_code_id, ...etc
columns in the project_code - id, name, ...etc*

```
SELECT b.id, code.name FROM bill b 
LEFT JOIN expense_distribution exp ON b.id=exp.bill_id
LEFT JOIN project_code code ON exp.project_code_id=code.id
LEFT JOIN item_distribution itm ON b.id=itm.bill_id
LEFT JOIN project_code code ON itm.project_code_id=code.id
```

I can't use the query with two times `project_code code` but I want `code.id` for both item and expense distributions because of the filter.

can someone guide me for the best approach to do that, I am using JPQL for the code in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this.
One way you can achieve this is by providing different aliases for same table and coalesce the fields.

```
SELECT b.id, COALESCE(c1.name, c2.name) as name FROM bill b 
LEFT JOIN expense_distribution exp ON b.id=exp.bill_id
LEFT JOIN item_distribution itm ON b.id=itm.bill_id
LEFT JOIN project_code c1 ON exp.project_code_id=c1.id
LEFT JOIN project_code c2 ON itm.project_code_id=c2.id;
```

Another approach would be, change the firsy and last two lines to

```
SELECT b.id, code.name FROM bill b 
LEFT JOIN expense_distribution exp ON b.id=exp.bill_id
LEFT JOIN item_distribution itm ON b.id=itm.bill_id
LEFT JOIN project_code code ON COALESCE(itm.project_code_id, exp.project_code_id)=code.id;
```

Third, change the last line from above to

```
LEFT JOIN project_code c1 ON exp.project_code_id=code.id OR itm.project_code_id=code.id
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine I have tried both 2nd and 3rd approaches

Answer (score 0):

### This is the tables creation:

```
 CREATE TABLE bill(
 id int(11),
 name varchar(10)
 ); 
 CREATE TABLE project_code(
 id int(11),
 name varchar(10)
 );
 CREATE TABLE expense_distribution(
 id int(11),
 bill_id int(11),
 project_code_id int(11),
 name varchar(10)
 );
 CREATE TABLE item_distribution(
 id int(11),
 bill_id int(11),
 project_code_id int(11),
 name varchar(10)
 );
```

### Based on these tables you can query the following query:

```
SELECT b.id, codes.name FROM bill b 
LEFT JOIN expense_distribution exp ON b.id=exp.bill_id
LEFT JOIN project_code codes ON exp.project_code_id=codes.id
LEFT JOIN item_distribution itm ON b.id=itm.bill_id and itm.project_code_id =codes.id
```